# Issue on Resetting Custom jQuery Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple custom jQuery Spinner at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2bvXh/2/) which is working fine for me but I am having issue on Resetting the value into initial. As you can see from the Demo and following code I am able to set the text of the `#targeteg` to `.html(targets[0]);` but if you start `+` or `-` the counter again continues the before setting value counting!

```
var targets = ["Target KM", "1,000 km", "3,000 km", "5,000 km", "7,000 km"];
var i = 0;
$("#plus").on("click", function () {
 if (i < 4) {
       $("#targeteg").html(targets[++i]);
 }
});
$("#minus").on("click", function () {
 if (i > 0) {
        $("#targeteg").html(targets[--i]);
  }
});
$("#resetForm").on("click", function () {
 mapReset();
 function mapReset() {
  $("#targeteg").html(targets[0]);
 }
});
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this then after resetting every thing starts from beginning like reloading the page time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `i=0` in the `reset` function

```
function mapReset() {
    i = 0;
    $("#targeteg").html(targets[0]);
}
```

[Working <kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/CD8cP/)

Comment: Thanks Karthikr, I just need 6 more minutes to accept the answer!

Comment: Check out my answer for some more improvements -- mainly fixing a bug when `i` is negative or larger than `targets.length`

Answer (score 1):

Your index, `i` is what determines the "current" item. The problem is that you're not resetting this index in your `mapReset()` function. You'll also want to change the index once you "roll over" the total number of items, or go into the negatives. Here is the updated code that should work as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var targets = ["Target KM", "1,000 km", "3,000 km", "5,000 km", "7,000 km"];
    var i = 0;

    $("#plus").on("click", function () {
        i++;

        if (i >= targets.length) {
            i = targets.length - 1; // Display the last item if we're at the end of the list
        }

        $('#targeteg').html(targets[i]);
    });

    $("#minus").on("click", function () {
        i--;

        if (i < 0) {
            i = 0; // Display the first item if we're at the beginning of the list
        }

        $('#targeteg').html(targets[i]);
    });

    // This function should be outside of any event handler, except perhaps a document.ready event
    function mapReset() {
        i = 0;
        $("#targeteg").html(targets[0]);
    }

    $("#resetForm").on("click", function () {
        mapReset();
    });

});
```